# How can I select a circle of data using X and Y grid coordinates in a SQL server database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, distance

This is a fun one, apologies for the lack of information but I don't have a clue about how to approach this.

I have a SQL Server database which is storing map coordinates against post area codes. For example postal area code BD6 is located at 414300m along the X axis and 429800m along Y axis. These values are in one table, in three separate columns, e.g:

```
PostAreaCode    AlongXAxis    AlongYAxis
BD6               414300       429800
```

I need to select all post area codes within a 161km radius of a particular post area code. So for example, the coordinates for BD6 are in the middle of the circle, and the edge of the circle is 161km away.

I can create a square around BD6 by using the BETWEEN keyword and doing something like...

```
SELECT PostAreaCode
FROM PostAreaCodeTable
WHERE AlongXAxis IS BETWEEN (414300-161000) AND (414300+161000)
AND AlongYAxis IS BETWEEN (429800-161000) AND (429800+161000)
```

...but I have no idea how to make it a circle. I consider myself to be pretty good at SQL but this is completely beyond me. Any help is much appreciated! Please explain mathsy answers as much as possible because maths is not my strong point. Thanks!

Comment: Is your table structure already set? Could you use a single column with a type of  geometry?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the formula `(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 <= r^2` as your where clause. `a` and `b` are the co-ordinates of the center and `x` and `y` are the co-ordinates of the point you want to check for and `r` is radius.
So, in your case, `a` is the X co-ordinate of center and `b` is Y co-ordinate of center, while `x` and `y` are the column names for the X and Y axis co-ordinates of the other points.

SQL would be:

```
SELECT PostAreaCode
FROM PostAreaCodeTable
WHERE ((AlongXAxis - 414300)^2 + (AlongYAxis - 429800)^2) <= (161000)^2
```

Comment: For more information on the distance formula, you can go to http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php.  You could also use this in your where clause (just a variation of the above): WHERE SQRT(SQUARE(414300-AlongXAxis) + SQUARE(429800-AlongYAxis)) <= 161000

Answer (score 0):

You can also take advantage of STDistance function if you're able to convert your points into coordinates.

I wrote the following assuming you cannot edit your actual table to include a coordinate column.

1st Create a temporary table and convert your x,y to Geometry Coordinates:

```
CREATE TABLE #PostAreaCodeTable2 (ID INT, AlongXAxis FLOAT, AlongYAxis FLOAT,  Coordinates GEOMETRY)

INSERT INTO #PostAreaCodeTable2
        ( ID ,
          AlongXAxis ,
          AlongYAxis ,
          Coordinates
        )
SELECT  ID ,
        AlongXAxis ,
        AlongYAxis,
        geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST( AlongXAxis AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST( AlongYAxis AS VARCHAR(10)) +')', 4326) 
FROM PostAreaCodeTable
```

Next join your normal table to the temp table with a where clause of the STDistance function:

```
DECLARE @source  GEOMETRY = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(414300  429800)',4326) --All Points are measured from X 414300 and from Y 429800

SELECT *, Coordinates.STAsText() AS Target,@source.STDistance(Coordinates) AS Distance
FROM PostAreaCodeTable PACT
JOIN #PostAreaCodeTable2  PACT2 on PACT.ID = PACT2.ID
WHERE @source.STDistance(Coordinates) <= 161000 --coordinates in table are less than or equal too 161000 from source
```